# NATVIS reinterpret type or alias type

Tags: visual-studio, natvis

Is there a way in natvis to reinterpret a type to an already natvis-defined type ? or alias it ?

For example, I'd like to do this kind of "trick" (really necessary in my context even if that does sound really weird to you, it's a question of JIT symbol generation)

```
<Type Name="std::vector&lt;*,*&gt;">
<DisplayString>{*(stl1.dll!std::vector&lt;$T0,$T1&gt *)this}</DisplayString>
</Type>
```

But it doesn't work to display the expand items, it just displays a string as value (which seems logical considering the 'DisplayString' role).

I've also tried with a `SmartPointer` trick, it does better but it turns out it doesn't work when there is base classes involved (it only displays the SmartPointer type and ignore completely inheritance)

Answer (score 1):

As you do not show your classes I can just show my own example code.

```cpp
struct A { int x, y; };
struct B { int x, y; };
struct C { int v, w; };

int main()
{
    A a{ 1,2 };
    B b{ 3,4 };
    C c{ 5,6 };
    return 0;
}
```

And the natvis:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
  <Type Name="A">
    <AlternativeType Name="B"/>
    <AlternativeType Name="C"/>
    <DisplayString>A {x}, {y}</DisplayString>
  </Type>
</AutoVisualizer>
```

This display as
[image]

As you can see the `AlternativeName` does the trick, but it is required on the natvis for the original class. And it requires that both classes have the same members/member names.

Please also note that when playing around with natvis it is a good idea to enable natvis debugging. Go to menu Tools/Options/Debugging/"Output Windows"/"General Output Settings" and set "Natvis diagnostic messages (C++ only)" to a useful value.

Comment: It does not answer my problem because has you said, it requires you know in advance every alternative name. What I want is to use another natvis without it being aware I will in advance. But thanks anyway for taking time to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you try to represent one type as another (transparently)? In your case you should use `ExpandedItem`. This should work:

```xml
  <Type Name="std::vector&lt;*,*&gt;">
    <Expand>
      <ExpandedItem>
        *(stl1.dll!std::vector&lt;$T0,$T1&gt *)this
      </ExpandedItem>
    </Expand>
  </Type>
```

But beware of recursion and side effects connecteed with `reinterpret_cast`