# Natvis type alias feature similar to typedef

Tags: visual-studio, natvis

I have some complex Item expressions where the type casts of nested template types are getting quite long and difficult to read. Is it possible to 'store' a type in the Natvis definition for reuse in the expression?

For example, in the following screenshot, the arrow is pointing to a type that I am casting to which is also being reused in the expression later. For readability and maintainability, it would be great if this can be aliased where we can then use the alias directly:

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61678053/17017616) answer your question?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I would like to use a type alias to simplify the complex syntax _inside_ the `Expand` section. The answer for the above question reinterprets a particular type in a certain way, however I cannot do that because I am reinterpreting bytes of an array.